# The Uniqueness of Baby-step-Giant-step Algorithm on DLP

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

The algorithm tells that, in the effort of solving $a^x \equiv b \text{ mod }N$:

1. Choose some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. Create the baby list: $\{1,a,a^2,...,a^{k-1}\}$
3. Create the giant list: $\{ba^{-k},ba^{-2k},...,ba^{-rk}\}$ where $rk > N$.

Claim: If two lists have intersection, then this DLP has a solution.

$\textit{Proof:}$ Given that these two lists have an intersection, meaning that, for some $m,n$.
\begin{align*}
    &a^n \equiv ba^{-mk} \text{ mod }N\\
    & a^{mk+n} \equiv b \text{ mod }N\\
\end{align*}
where $mk+n$ is $x$ as desired.

My question is, how do we know such solution is unique? or up to some equivalence? Is there any proof/counter-example for this?

Comment: Please delete the duplicate of this question on math.stackexchange since it's been answered here. Also, it is good practice to accept a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unique modulo the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $N$.

Suppose that there were two solutions:
$$a^{n_1}\equiv ba^{-m_1k}\mod N;\quad\quad a^{n_1}\equiv ba^{-m_2k}\mod N$$
this would tells us that
$$a^{m_1k+n_1}\equiv a^{m_2k+n_2}\pmod N$$
as both sides are $b\pmod N$. This then gives
$$a^{m_1k+n_1-(m_2k+n_2)}\equiv 1\mod N$$
which can only be true if $\mathrm{ord}_N(a)|m_1k+n_1-(m_2j+n_2)$ which is the same as
$$m_1k+N_1\equiv m_2+k_2\pmod{\mathrm{ord}_N(a)}.$$

An example of non-uniqueness is to take $N=15$, $a=7$ and $b=14$. Let's take $k=4$ and $r=4$. Our baby list is
$$\{1,7,14,8\}$$
and our giant list is
$$\{14,14,14,14\}$$
we get collisions $n=2$ with $m=1,2,3,4$ leading to possible values of $x=6,10,14,18$. All of these are equivalent modulo 4 which is the multiplicative order of 7 mod 15.